# Apache web server caching

Tags: grails

I have my load balancing apache server(just for redirecting the requests) which can communicate with 3 tomcat application servers. what is the best way to implement caching in this case and where can i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a commercial solution like Memcache on each of your webservers. You have to then configure your cache to talk to each of these webservers.